# WorkFlow on Document Set

Tags: workflow, flow

First I'll give you the goal of what I'm trying to do:

A user uploads multiple documents into a document set that has columns for required information. A workflow is initiated after all the columns have data and then the workflow uses the required column data as conditional arguments to route this document set to certain individuals.

Is this possible? If so, how should I go about this? My current approach was to create a document set with the columns and then create a Flow that starts after but I'm getting the feeling I'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Configuring columns to 'Required' rather than 'Optional' will prevent documents being saved (or checked-in - if you are using this feature).  I don't know about Flow, but in a Sharepoint Designer workflow you can use "IF statements" to initiate workflows.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. So my next question is; how can you prevent the workflow from starting until ALL the documents have been uploaded into the document set?

Comment: Maybe you could somehow count the number of documents uploaded in the document set, or else make Sharepoint return a value when a certain type of document has been uploaded.  e.g. if a Project document is uploaded, Sharepoint detects this and returns a value of 1.  If no Project document is uploaded is returns a value of 0.  If you have 5 types of documents, you'd need a score of 5 (1+1+1+1+1) to start the workflow.  I don't have the specifics of how to do this, but I'm just giving an idea for you to try out.